# How to destroy game object from unity hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy

I've created the below function to instantiate to game object, but I have to delete it one by one from hierarchy. How can I do that?

```
public void button() {
  Instantiate (player1 [i]);
  i = i + 1;

  destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroy wants to know what to destroy so you will need to give it a GameObject too destroy. In your case you can save the GameObject that you instantiate too a variable and than delete it.

```
GameObject player;
player = Instantiate (player[i]) as GameObject;

Destroy(player, 2f); // And now we can destroy the player after 2 seconds
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html